# Pre written Exception Handler for ASP.Net

Tags: exception, webforms

I'm looking for a Exception Handler for asp.net that does email notification including things like the values of form fields, session variables etc.

I have one that does it currently written by someone in house but it's not maintained and occasionally there are bugs in it causing give me only partial exception messages.

I tried googling it but all I could find were articles on how to write far more basic exception handlers than the one I have already.

Anyone know of any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/), perhaps you can extend it to include your customizations.

Comment: Just installed that, an excellent piece of software, really happy with it, thanks for your help :)